# How do you add an element to a folder in layers on Wix

Tags: velo

On Wix in the "Layers" panel, while editing a web page, how does someone merge one element to another in a folder?

I will use the image below as an example: How do you put "image4" into the "hoverBox17" folder?

[image]

Comment: The **wix tag** is for [the deployment tool](http://wixtoolset.org/) which is used to create MSI installers. The **wixcode tag** is for [the HTML tool](https://www.wix.com/) - which is what you seem to refer to. Please remove the WiX tag that you added back.

Comment: Thank you! I had no clue why the "wix" tag was being taken off before.

Comment: No problem, I should have pointed that out seeing as you are a new user. Welcome to Stackoverflow.